# What is the equivalent of Kubernetes Namespaces on Docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline to train myself, in order to do that i want to create a Docker swarm cluster with 3 nodes, 1 manager and 2 workers, I would like to know how can I do to isolate prod and preprod like we can do in kubernetes using namespaces?

Comment: I don't think Docker has any equivalent to Kubernetes namespaces, even in Swarm mode.  Remember that namespaces aren't really isolation in Kubernetes: it's very possible to have different-namespace Pods and storage on the same Nodes, and in your example a lower-environment Pod could have memory pressure that displaces a higher-environment Pod on the same Node.

Answer (score 1):

The stack name is actually a namespace and is even stored as such on labels on containers, services, volumes and networks: `com.docker.stack.namespace`.

`docker stack deploy` can be given a list of compose files to deploy into one "stack namespace", or can be called multiple times with a different compose file each time to do partial updates. Obviously you can't use `--prune` in the latter case.